# UnicodeEncodeError only when pipe into file and only on some PCs

Tags: python, unicode, utf-8

Many people had this problem, but the presented solutions dind't help me.

On my ubuntu machine the script runs without errors. But on my raspi keep getting this error:

```
UnicodeEncodeError: 'ascii' codec can't encode character '\xd6' in position 21: ordinal not in range(128)
```

The error hints to a German character (umlaut, ö) which should be printed using `print(a_name)`

What confuses me: When calling **`python3 myscript.py`** I don't get any errors on raspi. But with the call `python3 myscript.py`**`> output`** I get the error. Same with `nohup python3 myscript.py` or when run from crontab:

```
@reboot LANG=de_DE.UTF-8 /home/pi/launcher.sh > /home/pi/bot/logs/cronlog 2>&1
```

where *launcher.sh* uses the following code:

```
python3 myscript.py > pythonlog 2>&1
```

I checked **$LANG**

on my ubuntu pc (where I don't get any errors): **en_US.UTF-8**

on raspi: **de_DE.UTF-8**

Why am I getting this error message and how can I get rid of it?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Have you tried setting environment variable `PYTHONIOENCODING`?

```
export PYTHONIOENCODING=UTF-8
python3 myscript.py > pythonlog 2>&1
```

Comment: That was easier than I thought. Thank you.

Answer (score 3):

Under normal conditions, Python uses the locale to work out what encoding to apply to stdout.

When Python doesn't have an interactive session, i.e. when input or output is piped or redirected, Python defaults to "ASCII" encoding on stdout and stdin.

To override this behaviour, use the `PYTHONIOENCODING` environment variable to set an appropriate input/output encoding. E.g.

```
PYTHONIOENCODING=utf-8 echo "test €3.20" | myscript.py > output.txt
```

Comment: but when redirecting the output on my pc I had no problems, although PYTHONIOENCODING is not set there.

Comment: On your Rpi, run `locale` and see if there's any errors

Comment: You may want to update your question with side-by-side comparisons of behaviour from both machines. At the moment it's not clear what works and what doesn't.